# Excluding the first instance of an unbounded element in a BizTak map

Tags: dictionary, mapping, biztalk

I have a schema that is the souce with an element that is unbounded. I have a similar element on the destination schema that is also unbounded. I'm trying to figure out how in the map I can ignore the first instance in the source map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect the unbounded source record to an 'Iteration' functoid.
2. Connect the 'Iteration' to a 'Greater Than' functoid. Add a '1' as input paramter.
3. Connect the result of the 'Greater Than' to the unbounded record in the destination.